# How to configure Spring MVC HttpSecurity using Java config for login page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am building a Spring MVC application using Java config rather than xml, with Eclipse, Maven and Spring webmvc ver 4.2.4 and Spring security 4.0.3. I have it running on Tomcat 7. 
There are multiple jsp's that I can navigate from one to another, so the @RequestMappings are correct(they are listed in the configure( ) method below). I have logging set up with log4j with everything possible logged, so I can see my configurations and controllers are being called. During startup, the log file shows the mappings being set:

> ...RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET]}"...
>   ...RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Mapped "{[/login],methods=[POST]}" ...

My problem is the login screen does not POST to the correct method in the LoginController class when it is getting submitted, it keeps going to the "init" method which is annotated for the GET request.

Here is **SecurityConfig**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Autowired
   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/register","/about","/home","/demo").permitAll()
    //.loginProcessingUrl("/login")
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().formLogin().permitAll().loginPage("/login")
    .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/home");
   }
}
```

When //.loginProcessingUrl("/login") is uncommented, the autogenerated Spring login form appears and I can log in! So it works with the default form but not my form.

**LoginController.java** looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
   private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);

   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String init(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("LoginController login INIT!");
    return "login";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String login(@ModelAttribute LoginDTO loginObject, Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("LoginController login POST!");
    return "home";
   }

}
```

When the Spring default login page is submitted, it doesn't map to *my* LoginController. When my login.jsp is submitted, the request goes the init( ) method, not the login( ) method mapped to POST.

A snippet of my custom **login.jsp** I want to use instead of the default jsp:

```html
 <form:form action="${loginProcessingUrl}" method="post">
        <p>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="userId" name="userId"/>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
        </p>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Log in</button>
        </div>
 </form:form>
```

The framework is adding the CSRF token on the login page, which I can see on the browser, so that seems to be working but I'm not sure if it matters.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="ac81daad-f2e4-4357-a7a8-b7b10a67036f">
```

I am just learning Spring, and have been searching everywhere for some in depth explanation about how Spring Security works and is configured, especially the http object with all the chained methods. If anyone can direct me to a good reference for the latest Spring Security, I would appreciate it, or let me know what I need in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, you should remove the `@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)` from your controller and change the security configuration as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/", "/register", "/about", "/home", "/demo").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
    .formLogin()
      .loginPage("/login")
      .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
      .permitAll()
      .and()
    .logout()
      .logoutUrl("/logout")
      .logoutSuccessUrl("/home")
      .invalidateHttpSession(true);
   }
}
```

Spring will automatically handles your POST request with the Spring security filter and redirects you to your login form if necessary. Please make sure your login field names are correctly named "username" and "password":

```
<form:form action="${loginProcessingUrl}" method="post">
    <p>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
    </p>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Log in</button>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#jc-form for more information.

Comment: Yes, this works! I can log in and see the protected pages now. But I can't log out, so I will need to work on that part. The next step is to add JDBC log in, but you helped me over this hurdle. Thanks!